# Dynamic object validation with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm looking for a way to validate an object without using the [basic validation.yml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation) file which is too static for me.

I dynamically instance my objects with a factory, based on database values. That is the reason why I can't use validation.yml, I want to make my constraints dynamic depending on my database to.

I found a way to put dynamic constraints on a form (with the `AbstractType::setDefaultOptions()` function) but I just can't find how to validate a simple object with dynamic rules.

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could play with custom contraints according to this page http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

You might be able to write some custom stuff such as connect to database, check some things and get it valid or not.

Hope this helps